# How do I create a string as an output that uses specific words from a string input?

Tags: python, string, recursion

[image]

The question asks me to create a program that inputs two sentences (strings) and the program should output a new sentence (string) comprised of the first word of the first sentence, the second word of the second sentence, the third word of the first sentence, the fourth word of the second sentence and so on and so forth in that algorithm. I have no idea how to approach this question as I'm a beginner in coding, Python and programming in general. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? You should have tried to split the text into sentences, and split sentences into words. You should have located and read documentation on Python string operations and list operations.

Comment: Start by using `firstlist = first.split(' ')` to split the input into a list of words.

Comment: If you just want an easy solution, it's `" ".join(word for pair in zip(first.split(), second.split()) for word in pair)` (and if this is for a class, you should research those functions enough to be able to explain if the teacher asks how it works).  If you want to learn how to solve problems like this on your own you'll need to ask more specific questions -- as another commenter asked, what have you tried?  what specific parts did you get stuck on?